# composer me tira error parar instalar adminlte o laravel voyager

Tags: laravel, composer

cuando intento instalar

> composer require jeroennoten/laravel-adminlte

cuanbdo esta descargando    **- Downloading almasaeed2010/adminlte (v3.1.0)**

Da el siguiente error:

Failed to download almasaeed2010/adminlte from dist: curl error 28 while downloading https://codeload.github.com/ColorlibHQ/AdminLTE/legacy.zip/c641d7f5716ed47e76f70ab16e05ae41420120b8: Operation timed out after 300000 milliseconds with 3319601 out of 26582377 bytes received

---

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.

[Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessTimedOutException]
The process "git clone --no-checkout "https://github.com/ColorlibHQ/AdminLTE.git" "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\alma
saeed2010\adminlte" && cd /D "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\almasaeed2010\adminlte" && git remote add composer "https
://github.com/ColorlibHQ/AdminLTE.git" && git fetch composer && git remote set-url origin "https://github.com/ColorlibHQ/AdminLTE.git"
&& git remote set-url composer "https://github.com/ColorlibHQ/AdminLTE.git"" exceeded the timeout of 300 seconds.

Espero alguien me pueda ayudar. intente desinstalar composer volverlo a instalar. reinstale laragon y sigue igual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes una conexión lenta o el paquete es muy grande.
Para cambiar el tiempo del timeout puedes usar lo siguiente:

```
composer config --global process-timeout 9000
```

Comment: Ya lo hice. pero igual. es estresante. no hay forma de instalar los paquetes manual?

Comment: Si, descargando a mano cada dependencia, y a su vez sus dependencias hasta que llegues a una que no tenga (puedes tener que hacer 100-200 descargas, por lo que no es muy rentable)